# How can I rename all the existing carrierwave uploaded files?

Tags: rename, carrierwave

I have been using Carrierwave for file uploads for some time.  I did not try to rename the files as they got uploaded.  Now I want to give each file a random name and a file extension that's consistent with the content type.  I read the wiki and other sites, and it was recommended that in the uploader, I could:

```
def filename
  "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
end

private
def secure_token
  #implement the secure token
end
```

It worked fine on files uploaded *after* these additions to the uploader.  But I got many files that were uploaded before this change.  I was wondering if someone could tell me how to migrate the old files.

I tried adding a method to the uploader:

```
def rename_file!
  model.update_attribute mounted_as, "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}"
  recreate_versions!
end
```

then in the rails console, I tried calling this on an model with attachment.  However, I found that the `mounted_as` column of the model never got updated, though on the file system, various versions of the file were created with the new name.  When I inspected the `mounted_as` field of the model, it did not get updated.  The log actually said the column was updated with the old value.

How can I get the `mounted_as` column on the model updated?

In addition, it seemed like the old files with the old names were still on the file system.  Is there a way to remove them?  I tried adding a line:

```
file.move_to File.join("#{File.dirname file.path}, "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}")
```

in the `rename_file!` method.  It renamed the files, but did not update the `mounted_as` column on the model.  So accessing its URL resulted in a 404.

Comment: I would do this in a rake task

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a little old now, but perhaps useful for others.

After updating your Uploader with the `filename` method, like you have, you could run this from the Rails console;

```
Post.all.each do |p|
  p.avatar.recreate_versions!
  p.save!
end
```

In the current version of CarrierWave, this will both rename the file and update the model record.

`Post` of course is the model name and `avatar` the column on which you are mounting the uploader, so change those as required.

Comment: This works, but if the `store_dir` has changed, it will result in the file not being found. [I opened an issue with CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2328), because I don't think this is the intended behavior.